# JavaScript onchange does not trigger on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Somehow to onchange fuction does not trigger properly after I Switch the Radio button. Currently I get no log message with "circle uncheck" or "arrow uncheck". The HTML Looks like this:

```js
var drawingArrow = document.getElementById('drawing-arrow-shape'),
  drawingCircle = document.getElementById('drawing-circle-shape');

drawingCircle.onchange = function() {
  console.log("on change circle btn");
  if ($("#drawing-circle-shape").is(":checked")) {
    console.log("circle checked");
  } else {
    console.log("circle uncheck");
  }
};

drawingArrow.onchange = function() {
  console.log("on change arrow btn");
  if ($("#drawing-arrow-shape").is(":checked")) {
    console.log("arrow checked")
  } else {
    console.log("arrow uncheck");
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <input type="radio" name="drawing-shape" id="drawing-arrow-shape">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <input type="radio" name="drawing-shape" id="drawing-circle-shape">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></i>
</label>
```

Comment: You asked this yesterday. We provided an answer for this. You get no message because you have to separate radio buttons in different scopes. Do you want them to behave "This or this"?

Comment: Following your update the code now works, as you can see from the snippet I added to the question. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the `,` after the second variable definition should be a `;`. This is confusing the JS interpreter as it thinks the next statement will be a variable definition, when in fact it's a variable setter.

You should however note that you can improve your logic by using `addEventListener()` on the elements directly. You can then just use the `this` keyword to reference the element without having to use jQuery to select an element you already have a reference to. Try this:

```js
document.getElementById('drawing-arrow-shape').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked)
    console.log('arrow checked');
});

document.getElementById('drawing-circle-shape').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) 
    console.log('circle checked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <input type="radio" name="drawing-shape" id="drawing-arrow-shape">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <input type="radio" name="drawing-shape" id="drawing-circle-shape">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></i>
</label>
```

Comment: I have the ; failed with the copy

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Well your update fixed the problem... making the question pointless. All my question can offer you now is the improvement to your logic.

Comment: But why does it not return the console.log from the else branch?

Comment: That's because the `change` event only fires on the element you click on, not the one that was previously checked.

Comment: I Need to check wether each button is unchecked what a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why? It's a radio button. You know what button is checked (ie the one that raised the event) and only one radio at a time *can be checked*. Therefore all other radio buttons with the same name are not checked.

Comment: True, I am missing some logic this morning:D

Answer (score 0):

I made a small change in your Js and now it is working please check below changes I made

```
var drawingArrow = document.getElementById('drawing-arrow-shape');
var drawingCircle = document.getElementById('drawing-circle-shape');
```

Just removed comma and made separate variables.

```js
var drawingArrow = document.getElementById('drawing-arrow-shape');
      var  drawingCircle = document.getElementById('drawing-circle-shape');


    drawingCircle.onchange = function() {
        console.log("on change circle btn");
        if($("#drawing-circle-shape").is(":checked")) {
            console.log("circle checked");
        } else {
            console.log("circle uncheck");
        }
    };

    drawingArrow.onchange = function() {
        console.log("on change arrow btn");
        if($("#drawing-arrow-shape").is(":checked")) {
            console.log("arrow checked")
        } else {
            console.log("arrow uncheck");
        }
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <input type="radio" name="drawing-shape" id="drawing-arrow-shape">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <input type="radio" name="drawing-shape" id="drawing-circle-shape">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></i>
    </label>
```

Comment: What's the change? Should I get my magnifying glass out? :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if you have one please use :) otherwise I just made var drawingArrow = document.getElementById('drawing-arrow-shape');
      var  drawingCircle = document.getElementById('drawing-circle-shape'); to in JS

Comment: @Yogeh plz add your comment on question section .

Comment: I have the ; failed with the copy

Comment: Yes @Olipol that is something typo

Comment: But why does it not return the console.log from the else branch?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change these 2 statements:

```
   var drawingArrow = document.getElementById('drawing-arrow-shape');
        drawingCircle = document.getElementById('drawing-circle-shape');
```

There was a `','` on the end of both which was causing the issue. Replacing that with `';'` fixed it.

Comment: Oh sorry I have a ; failed with the copy

Comment: @Olipol yes that will fix the issue. Your code is now working please try that.